# Getting "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: HTTP Server cannot be loaded: No implementation of HttpServerFacade found on classpath." error

Tags: h2o

I am trying out the distributed random forest implementation of H2O using sparkling-water. But I am facing the following error when I run the spark-submit command.

```
Exception in thread "H2O Launcher thread" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at water.init.NetworkInit.initializeNetworkSockets(NetworkInit.java:77)
    at water.H2O.startLocalNode(H2O.java:1621)
    at water.H2O.main(H2O.java:2081)
    at water.H2OStarter.start(H2OStarter.java:22)
    at water.H2OStarter.start(H2OStarter.java:47)
    at org.apache.spark.h2o.backends.internal.InternalBackendUtils$$anonfun$6$$anon$1.run(InternalBackendUtils.scala:173)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: HTTP Server cannot be loaded: No implementation of HttpServerFacade found on classpath. Please refer to https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/TN-13 for details.
    at water.webserver.iface.HttpServerLoader.<clinit>(HttpServerLoader.java:16)
    ... 6 more
```

I have tried out the solution mentioned at the location https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/TN-13

but for some reason it still isn't able to find the `ai.h2o:h2o-jetty-8` on the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding the following maven coordinates to the packages option in spark-submit

`--packages ai.h2o:h2o-jetty-8:3.24.0.3`